# Can CSS place <td> tags one under another like <tr> do

Tags: css, html-table

There is a webpage with several tables. One of them has a single `tr` and >15 `td`s inside. While there are becoming more and more `td`s, they start to get out of screen.

I want to position them vertically, like if they were `tr`s or `div`s. But:

1. I'm afraid to break something while editing website HTML (probably it is java template);
2. I don't want to patch page with JS, because it would be an additional problem/question of how/where to put that code.

So I would like to solve it with CSS, because in that way it is easy to set up my personal custom CSS, if my colleagues would say that my redesign sucks while going beyond screen borders was cool. Also CSS is easier to *edit and see results in real time* than edit desctructing JS.

Comment: Tables don't work like that. `td` elements are columns and `tr` elements are rows.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I know. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Maybe use divs instead of a table?

Comment: @JimmyMattsson *I'm afraid to break something while editing website HTML*

Comment: Make the `td` elements `display:block`?  - http://jsfiddle.net/VbgZw/

Comment: @Nakilon I said that because forcing them not to behave like that would go against the specification.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Making list items appear horizontally via `display: inline-block` goes against the specification of lists, your point?  CSS is for modifying the default appearance of HTML elements.  Nowhere in the specification does it say "oh by the way, you're not allowed to take table-cell elements and make them act like block elements"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As James Donnelly tells you in the comments, I think that's not the normal behaviour of tables. Also, I don't know if you are using a table for layout or for tabular data. So, I think was preferible to change the markup into something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qE3kT/1/).

As you can see, I did a replace: all `<tr>` into `<div class="row">` and all `<td>` into `<div>`. I replaced all the `tr`and `td` closing tags too into closing divs, and then I set all the inner `<div>` with `float:left`. This puts all "td's" inline, just like a table, but when they reach the border of the page starts stacking down.

There are another fixes that comes into my mind if you want to preserve the markup.

- You could style the `<td>` as `display:block`. This puts all your `<td>` one under another, but this doesn't work on IE7 / IE8.
- You could enclose all table in a div and set that div with `overflow-x:scroll` and to make sure `max-width:100%`, as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qE3kT/).

Hope this helps, and don't be afraid to break things, sometimes is the best learning method! ;)

Comment: Too bad James Donnelly is wrong.  Modifying the display property of table elements is perfectly valid.  Whether or not browsers honor it properly is something entirely different.  Stuffing tabular data into a bunch of divs because you "don't like the look of tables" is just as wrong as using tables for layout purposes.

Comment: @cimmanon I think the W3C info for this point it's a little confuse, but reading the [table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#table-model) I deduce that the `td` elements displayed as rows, breaks the table model. But I'm not part of the stuff of W3C, so, I'm going to edit the answer to make clear that's only my opinion ;)

Comment: None of that has anything to do with CSS.  Table elements need to retain specific display properties (td, th = table-cell, tr = table-row, table = table, etc) for the behavior defined in that document to apply.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason because I didn't mention any specificaction in my answer, only say "that's not the normal behaviour of tables", and certainly it isn't. I'm not sure to understand how can I improve my answer, or why it is incorrect, excuse me (my english skills are a bit poor...). So, I only expect any of the three possible fixes I posted will be useful for the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to loop through each tr and td and increasing the height of the containing tr, relative positioning each based on the size of the first. It would only work in certain situations where there were no colspans/rowspans and padding may cause issues.

```
var table = $('table');
var cellHeight = $('td',table).first().height();
var cellWidth = $('td',table).first().width();
var runningTop = 0;
$('tr',table).each(function(i,row) {
    var rowCells = $(this).find('td');
    $(this).height(cellHeight*(rowCells.length))
    rowCells.each(function(x,cell) {
        $(cell).css({ "position": "relative","top":(cellHeight*x)+runningTop,"left": "-"+(cellWidth*(x))+"px" });
        runningTop = runningTop+cellHeight;
    });
});
```

Needs work but here's a Fiddle of the idea http://jsfiddle.net/hPhRX/1/

Answer (score 0):

make  display: inline-table;
It worked for me.