# How do I force <td> within a table row, below another <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this block of html. I need Content 3 to display below Content 2.
Content 1 is quite lengthy and fills quite far down.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>(Content 1)</td>
        <td>(Content 2)</td>
        <td>(Content 3)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/15uuL43x/

I would prefer using jquery. I can change the css, or transform the tags, but I cannot change the td to divs or tr. I can create new tr's or move things around.
Is this possible?

Comment: Using jQuery (or Javascript) you can completely change the DOM.  I don't understand what you are looking to achieve, though.  You currently have a table with one row and three columns.  Do you want a table with two rows and two columns?  Or a table with one row and two columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CSS place <td> tags one under another like <tr> do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086034/can-css-place-td-tags-one-under-another-like-tr-do). Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22816078/781765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea would be to set row span on the first cell, add a new row and append the last td to the new row.

```js
var tds = $("tr td");
tds.eq(0).attr('rowspan', '2');
$("<tr/>").append(tds.eq(2)).appendTo("table");
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border : 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>(Content 1)</td>
        <td>(Content 2)</td>
        <td>(Content 3)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine table cells as floats: https://jsfiddle.net/efedorenko/15uuL43x/6/

```
tr {
    overflow: hidden;
}
    .td1 {
        float: left;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .td2 {
        float: right;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .td3 {
        clear: right;
        float: right;
        background-color: orange;
    }
```